# How do I detect field changes in EF?

Tags: entity-framework

In EF4, I want to know if some fields has been changed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var propertyFooIsModified = 
    Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(someEntity)
                              .GetModifiedProperties.Any(p => p == "Foo");
```